# Android - is it possible to display an iTunes podcast to users and have them listen while being right on the app?

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to add an educational podcast for people to listen right on the app.

I tried to create web view. But I think only the first time the website is fetched, the user remains inside the app. Once the user clicks any link in the WebView, the mobile browser seems to take over and take them outside of the app.

Actually, even if I load the podcast channel like this url for example:
https://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/entrepreneur-on-fire-seth/id564001633?mt=2&ign-mpt=uo%3D4

Then I can't play the podcasts because the play button doesn't render on the individual podcast shows.

Is there a way to somehow allow them to play the podcasts right inside the app? Or a workaround I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: you can get the audio by using a XML parser. You get the content from the URL then parse it and you can display it in a listView and then play the audio with MediaPlayer. It's longer than using a webview but better i think

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using setWebViewClient so it keeps opening the urls inside the webView?

Here is the way I use it:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For the first part on navigation, have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation), it has a great example on how to stop the browser from launching.

For the second part, try `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`I suspect that the page is using javascript. One thing to note, is that the WebView is limited in terms of javascript and if the page was not designed with mobile in mind, you may have trouble getting this to work. Might be better to see if there is another way to get a hold of the podcast audio stream.